# Plus sign isn't in the middle

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chemfig

[image: How it currently looks like]
As you can see in the picture the plus sign is a little bit under the middle. How can I fix it? 
Here's a short-code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart[][west]
    % first molecule
    \chemfig{[:30]
            **6(
                -
                -
                    (-[0]C
                        (=[2]\charge{45=\|, 135=\|}{O})
                        (-[0]\charge{0=\., 90=\|, 270=\|}{O})
                    )
                -
                -
                -
                -
            )
        }
        \arrow{0}[,0]
        \+
        % second molecule
        \chemfig{
            **6(------)
        }
    \schemestop
    \\
    % product
    \schemestart
        \arrow{->}
        \chemfig{[:90]
            **6(
                -
                    (-[0]C
                        (-[0]\charge{90=\|, 270=\|}{O}
                            (-[0]C
                                (-[0]C)
                                (-[2]H)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                -
                -
                -
                -
                -
            )
        }
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

According to the docs I could add an offset to the plus sign:
[image: Doc image]
but isn't there a better solution than trying to find the correct offset?

Comment: @Bernard thank you for editing it! I don't know what I'm doing wrong but somehow the first image doesn't pop up...

Comment: To highlight code, in the editing window, the toolbar has a pair of braces icon: you just have to select  the code and click on the icon.

Comment: Hm... somehow it didn't load the beginning ("Hello guys!") I removed it and now the first image pops up. Anyway I though that I could write \`\`\`latex <code>\`\`\` to start a codeblock

Comment: It's simpler clicking on an icon… For the image inclusion, did you start a new line first?

Comment: yeah but it should be fixed now (I can see it now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys... I just found a solution: Just wrap the plus sign between two zero-length arrows, than it will look like this (I continued writing the reaction so don't be suprised if it doesn't look like the reaction of the question):
[image: Solution]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart[][west]
% first molecule
\chemfig{[:30]
        **6(
            -
            -
                (-[0]C
                    (=[2]\charge{45=\|, 135=\|}{O})
                    (-[0]\charge{0=\., 90=\|, 270=\|}{O})
                )
            -
            -
            -
            -
        )
    }
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \+{0.5cm, 0.5cm}
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    % second molecule
    \chemfig{
        H
        -[7]C
            (-[6]**6(------))
        =[0]C
            ( -[1]H)
            ( -[7]H)
    }
\schemestop
\\
% product
\schemestart
    \arrow{->}
    \chemfig{[:90]
        **6(
            -
                (-[0]C
                    (-[0]\charge{90=\|, 270=\|}{O}
                        (-[0]C
                            (-[0]C)
                            (-[2]H)
                        )
                    )
                )
            -
            -
            -
            -
            -
        )
    }
\schemestop
\end{document}
```